# How can I change the title of the search results page?

Tags: 7, search

I've done much searching on this issue and most, if not all, of the results refer to the html tag in the head. I'm **not** trying to change the `head>title` tag in the html, I'm trying to change body content.

Currently, this is being output as "Search Content" like so:

```
<a href="/search">
  Search
</a><a href="/search/node">
  Content
</a>
```

I have no idea where either of those pieces of text are stored. They aren't in any template file I have, and if they are set somewhere in drupal, it's hidden to me.

Comment: it's defined in the `hook_search_info()` function.

Comment: Ok - is that to say that I need to modify the search module's use of this function? Or could I add this hook to my template.php file to override the title?

Comment: above comment is more of a "here is the origin" comment. You can change the title in many functions - `search-results.tpl.php` file using `drupal_set_title()` for example. I can't write a proper answer on this device.